# What is the mantra for Shiva and Parvati equivalent to "SITA RAM" and "RADHA KRISHNA"?

Tags: vishnu, shiva, mantras, parvati

Even Vishnu has mantras like "OM LAKSHMI NARAYANA NAMAHA" but what is the famous mantra for the couple SHIVA/PARVATI?

Comment: I think UmaMaheswaraabhyam Namaha: preceded by Om

Comment: Uma Maheswar as Tezz said and also Gauri Shankara.

Comment: @Rickross can you make it an answer, like the benefits of the mantra, usage like that? That will be great.

Comment: Ok let me see if i can find sources. Yet another is Hara-Gauri. @KishyNivas

Answer (score 5):

I have not came across any specific mantra for the Shiva/Parvati. But I think this is you are looking for so far.

Karpur Gauram Karunavtaaram is an ancient Sanskrit Shloka related to Lord Shiva, and a popular aarti in Shaivism.
शिवयजुर्मन्त्र

Śivayajurmantra

कर्पूरगौरं करुणावतारम्

karpūragauraṁ karuṇāvatāraṁ

संसारसारं भुजगेन्द्रहारम् |

sansārsāram bhujagendrahāram |

सदा वसन्तं हृदयारविन्दे

sadāvasantaṁ hṛdayāravinde

भवं भवानीसहितं नमामि ||

**Translation:**

bhavaṁ bhavānīsahitaṁ namāmi ||

karpūragauraṁ:- The one who is as pure as camphor.

karuṇāvatāraṁ:- The personification of compassion or the embodiment of compassion.

sansārsāram:- The one who is the essence of the world

bhujagendrahāram:- The one with the serpent king as his garland

sadāvasantaṁ hṛdayāravinde:- Always residing in the lotus-like heart
(Explanation: Hridaya aravinde means 'in the heart that is (as pure as) lotus'. Lotus, though born in the muddy waters, is untouched by the mud around it. Similarly Lord Shiva always (Sada) resides (vasantham) in the hearts of beings which are not affected by worldly matters.)

bhavaṁ:- To the Lord

bhavānīsahitaṁ namāmi:- Accompanied by the Goddess Bhavani (form of Parvati, Shiva's consort), I bow

Reference : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karpuragauram_Karunavtaaram

Answer (score 3):

I assume that you are seeking Uma Maheswara Stotram written by Adi Shankra, check the portion below, click [here](http://www.hindupedia.com/en/Uma_Maheswara_Stotram) for complete Stotram:

> Nama Sivabhyam, Nava Youvanabhyam, Paraspara slishta Vapurtharabhyam,
>   Nagendra Kanya vrusha Kethabhyam, Namo Nama Sankara Parvatheebhyam
>
> Salutations to Lord Shiva and Goddess Shivaa, Who are always in fresh
>   stage of youth, Who cling to each other in tight embrace, Of whom one
>   is the daughter of the mountain, And the other is one whose symbol is
>   a bull, Salutations and salutations to Lord Sankara And to that
>   Goddess Parvathy.